# CMake automatically sets CXX upon first execution

Tags: cmake, environment-variables

I have a C++ project where I do not want to specify a "default" compiler, since it needs to be compiled with many different compilers in different contexts.  (In unit testing and end-to-end testing, I do test it with a few different compilers.)

I tried to implement this in CMake by requiring that the user set the environment variable `CXX` before the initial CMake configuration (executing `cmake`).  (I also have it drop a file to store the value to ensure that any subsequent invocation of `make` has the same value of `CXX` set, but that's irrelevant to the rest of the question.)

However, this doesn't actually work.  Here is a minimal example and the execution output.

CMake configuration file:

```
project(test)

if(DEFINED ENV{CXX})
    message("\$CXX = ${CXX}")
else()
    message(SEND_ERROR "\$CXX must be defined by the user to compile this project.")
endif()

add_executable(test)
```

First execution of `cmake`:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.3.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.3.4
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
$CXX =
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: test


-- Build files have been written to: /hnfs/torcfs03n06a/vol/ret_users_sasquire/inactive/bugs/cmake
```

Second invocation of `cmake` in the same directory (with no cleanup):

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (message):
  $CXX must be defined to compile this project.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

So the test whether `CXX` is defined is clearly working the *second* time, but not the first time.

Two questions:

1. How *should* I be implementing this?
2. I think that it is a somewhat reasonable behavior for `cmake` to set `CXX` internally if it wasn't set by the user, and I suspect that's what's happening in the first case.  But why are the first and second runs different?

Some comments on item 1:

- There are some obvious things, like introducing my own environment variable that is used to determine the compiler that `cmake` won't set on its own.  But ideally I would just be able to get CMake to forego defining `CXX`, for example.  Or perhaps there is functionality along the lines of GNU `make`'s [origin function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Origin-Function.html), which can distinguish between variables set in the environment and variables set by default or in the makefile.
- If the answer is basically "don't do that" (i.e. don't make the user define the compiler), then I am not going to consider it a constructive answer.

Comments on item 2:

- To me, this looks like a bug in CMake, where it sets `CXX` while detecting the C++ compiler, and then it does not unset that variable afterwards.  But is there a different way to look at this?  Or is there documentation regarding this?

Comment: `project(test LANGUAGES NONE)`
ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/enable_language.html

Comment: If you don't specify a language in the `project()` command, CMake will automatically detect the C and CXX compilers. This is the *expected* behavior, unless you add `LANGUAGES NONE`.

Comment: This also sounds like a good solution.  But would this also prevent it from testing that the value of `CXX` that you choose is a valid C++ compiler with certain expected features?  This seems like a nice thing, so if there is a tiebreaker between the two solutions, this would be it.

Comment: Setting the environment variable CXX isn't the only way for someone to specify which compiler to use.  You can also set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER on the command line or in a toolchain file.  I can't say for sure but for the first run the environment might have been altered to set CXX when it starts spawning the instances for the compiler detection and checks.  That seems kind of strange and I would not have expected that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check `CXX` environment variable **before** `project()` call:

```
if(DEFINED ENV{CXX})
    message("\$CXX = ${CXX}")
else()
    message(SEND_ERROR "\$CXX must be defined by the user to compile this project.")
endif()

project(test)
```

`CXX` variable is used by CMake when detecting C++ compiler, and exactly `project()` call triggers that detection. So, why do you check the variable after the `project()` call if bad things have already happened?

---

As for setting the `CXX` environment variable internally by CMake, I would suggest to not care about that.

Anywhere, setting this variable for other purposes (not for compiler detection) would contradict with CMake usage of that variable.

For finding out which C++ compiler is used after the `project()` call, it is simpler to read `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` CMake variable.

Comment: This works.  Thanks!  I wasn't aware that the `project()` command is what causes all of the compiler settings to be triggered, nor that the exact placement of the `project` command actually has an effect on execution.  I thought of it more as just setting a title for the project you're working on.  (Yes, I am a CMake newbie and have not read all of the documentation yet.)